# Using a property of collection to compare with rest of the properties in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an expression tree which needs to generate a calculative property from the collection of sample class! I'm new to expression tree, and for this I'm forced to go with the expression tree method and I'm not able to figure out on how to proceed!

Consider the example class

```
class Sample
{
    int id;
    string s;
}
```

the data set

```
sampleData = {
    {id =1 , s = "source", charRatio(Calculative prop) = 100 },
    {id =2 , s = "test", charRatio = 66 },
    {id =3 , s = "test", charRatio = 66 },
    {id =4 , s = "test", charRatio = 66 },
    {id =5 , s = "test", charRatio = 66 },
    {id =6 , s = "test", charRatio = 66 }
}
charRatio = obj.len / sourceObj.len   (Percentage)

//Without expression tree i would simply use something like
var sourceLen = sampleData.Where(x => x.id ==1).select(x => x.s).Length;
var result = sampleData.Where(x => x.s.Length/sourceLen > 50);
```

Note : The charRatio is an calculative property, added here for clarification!

I can solve the issue with linq with just finding the property with id = 1, and using it against each property of the collection!

is it possible to do the same using expression tree?? if yes can someone guide me at the right direction?

Comment: Your sample data looks like json, not c#. `.select(x => x.s).Length` wont compile, I assume you mean something like `sampleData.First(x => x.id ==1).s.Length`? However this sounds like an XY problem. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you think expression trees are the solution?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah the data I posted is in json format its not the actual code its just a representation of the data! what I'm trying to solve is a dynamic filter which uses expression trees `Expression<Func<model,bool>>` in this format I need to convert the linq that i posted to expression is that possible?

Comment: What linq? what expression? If you can't provide a working sample, and describe why you think it needs to be dynamic. I can't provide an "Expression Tree". But more importantly Why?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm talking about the `souceLen` and `result` query i mentioned in the question! I'm working on a wpf project which has a search functionality with complex filter's! and on the API side i convert the filter's selected by the user into an expression! basically thats how the whole system is designed! I have to add a new filter  which is to return the result which has characterratio condition and in order for it to work i need to convert the filter configs into expressions something like `Expression<Func<Sample,bool>> exp = null; exp = t => t.charRatio > someValue` CR is calc prop!

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I just want to know if it's possible to have a variable kind of thing in expressions where i can retrieve the sourceLen and then use it across the other properties of a collection

Comment: @JeremyLakeman atleast please tell me if its doable or am i wasting my time looking into something that cant be done

Comment: So you want something like https://github.com/dbelmont/ExpressionBuilder? I wouldn't recommend building it yourself.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman We already have something like it! we use telerik! but the problem I'm  facing is generating a calculative property based on the value of one sibling class among the collection!